# Scala-Play framework. Access is denied when run play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a problem with the Play framework (Scala). After I create a project, an error is thrown when running it..I using command "run". Windows 8.1. Pls help me

Detailed error:

> FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Users\dophu\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_a6a70b66\xsbt\MakeSettings$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class
>   (Access is denied)!

Comment: What command did you run before this error occured? Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: Looks like sbt would like to modify the file during on-demand compilation and failed. Could this file be locking by something? Another sbt task, eg.
Try to remove whole sbt_... folder in Temp and rerun.

Comment: I using command "run". Windows 8.1. Pls help me

Comment: `sbt run`, `activator run` or `play run`?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the permissions of the project so your user can write in all of the files. Here you have some help on doing it:

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/take-ownership-of-files-folder-and-change-permissions-in-windows-8/